# Как установить фиксированное положение при изменение размеров экрана

Tags: css, адаптивность

Пытаюсь реализовать кнопку удаления. Вся проблема заключается в неправильном `css`, при масштабировании страницы, либо изменения размеров окна браузера, крестики выходят из элемента `li` и я понимаю почему, но написать правильный `css` не получается. Прошу помощи.

HTML

```
<ul>
   <span class='close'>крестик</span>
   <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.close::after {
    content: '\2716';
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 600px;
    padding: 1.07em 0px;
}
```

Без изменения размера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С изменением 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Крестики должны быть в красном блоке `li`, а не выходить за его пределы.
Идеи?

Comment: Сделайте просто положение процентами, например 60%. Конечно, на одном месте крестики не будут, но и выходить из окна или налезать на текст тоже не будут. А почему вам так не нравится? Красиво смотрится

Comment: @Ver Nick с процентами та же проблема, ездят по всему `li`. Ну красиво не красиво не имеет смысла, просто нужно чтобы они были фиксированные в `li`, а если например я открою эту страницу на очень широким монитором, они вообще уедут фиг знает куда, это не хорошо)

Comment: Попробуй добавить параметр отступа, раз объект - absolute. Например:
right: 10px;

Comment: А можете весь код показать? Не бойтесь, не украду ))

Comment: @VerNick, пробовал, после изменения экрана он уходит влево

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поместите крестик в `li` и задайте ему(`li`) `position: relative` и будет он у вас размещаться относительно края `li` в независимости от его размера.

```css
.container {
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.list__item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
.list__item-remove {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 25px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item">Item <span class="list__item-remove">X</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

А лучше сделайте полный пример, тогда будет более полный и наглядный ответ.

Comment: тоже пробовал, если поместить в li длинна текста будет сбивать крестик, вообщем та же проблема

Comment: @karaname, обновил пример. Не знаю как вы делали, но все работает.

Comment: понял ошибку свою, я забыл поставить в `li` `relative`, всё работает, спасибо!

Comment: @karaname, на будущее - это один из возможных вариантов. Еще можно сделать с помощью `float`, `flex`, `CSS Grids` и таблиц.